# Length of wav file in msec

Tags: matlab

I know you can just do:

```
[w,fs] = wavread('file.wav');
length = length(w)/fs;
```

But I'm trying to trim down the noise at the beginning and end of a file and get the duration of the bulk of the recording by going through the waveform matrix in sample chunks then comparing the biggest sample in that chunk to a threshold, if it's bigger than that threshold then start measuring, stop measuring when it's less than the threshold.

Here's my attempt:

```
w = w(:,1);
thold = max(w) * .04;
nwindows = 1000;
counter = 0;
start = true;
for i = 1:nwindows:length(w)
  if (max(w(i:min(i+49,length(w)))) > thold)
      counter = counter + 1;
  elseif (max(w(i:min(i+49,length(w)))) < thold && start == true)
      break;
  end
end

result = counter/fs;
```

Just need to figure out how to get milliseconds out of counter now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code snippet, counter is the index in the wav file that you are looking for. To convert to ms, we need to use the wav file sample rate:

```
 timeInSec = counter/fs;
```